# FakeHttpServer quebra ao atualizar para o Jetty 9

Tags: java, maven, jetty

Eu estou migrando uma aplicação que usava o `Jetty 7.4.5.v20110725` para o `Jetty 9.3.0.M2`, usando o `Maven`. Eu já atualizei o `javax.servlet-api` para a `versão 3.1.0`.

Mas, eu estou utilizando o [FakeHttpServer versão 0.3.0](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/se.dannej/fakehttpserver/0.3.0) para testes, e no momento não existe uma versão mais nova. Ele usa a classe `org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector` que costumava existir até o Jetty 8.x, mas não existe mais no Jetty 9.

Neste momento, o meu projeto quebra em tempo de execução com um `NoClassDefFoundError` por causa da classe removida do Jetty que o FakeHttpServer tenta usar, me impedindo de completar o upgrade do Jetty. Como posso consertar isso?

<sup>Nota: isto também foi postado no StackOverflow em inglês: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30309677/540552</sup>

Comment: Segundo as sugestões feitas [aqui](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ARQ-1419) e [aqui](http://jetty.4.x6.nabble.com/jetty-dev-Migrating-Jetty6-to-Jetty-9-SslSocketConnector-related-tp4961366p4961367.html), você pode usar a classe [`ServerConnector`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/ServerConnector.html).

Comment: @qmechanik O problema é ter que mexer em um código que não é meu, que é o FakeHttpServer. Na verdade eu nem esperava ter que mexer com isso, o motivo é que eu precisei mudar a versão do Jetty porque uma dependência precisava da versão 9, e fazer o upgrade não deveria causar maiores problemas, exceto que uma outra dependência usa o FakeHttpServer e este quebrou. Como resultado, esta mudança do Jetty me fez ter duas dependências mutuamente incompatíveis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal como respondido em inglês pelo Joakim Erdfelt no Stack Overflow em inglês, a única saída é atualizar o FakeHttpServer. Seja convencendo os autores originais a fazê-lo, ou seja fazendo isso eu mesmo.

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30311559/540552